# ID3 Tag editor for 13.04 & later

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3, id3

I have found some ID3 tag editor in the web but unfortunately they are no longer available in 13.04 repository. Can anyone give me some recommendation for an ID3 Tag editor program? I need features like being able to tag lots of files at once and to read/write embedded (**not linked**) album art cover to/from Mp3 files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both EasyTag and PuddleTag are available in the raring repos
http://projects.gnome.org/easytag/
http://puddletag.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks easytag works for me (somewhat similar to mp3tag), since I don't know how to use puddletag yet.

Answer (score 4):

I've found Puddletag to be a great tag editor. It does multiple files and allows images to be embedded. It came in really handy for me when I was debugging code that writes MP3 and MP4 tags, but it works with lots of types of tags.

You should be able to get it from the repository via `sudo apt-get install puddletag`

If not, there's always the PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/puddletag
sudo apt-get update
sudp apt-get install puddletag
```

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded Puddletag. After editing tag for files, how do I save it? The floppy disk icon doesnt do anything.

Comment: It's been a little while since I've used it, but if I remember correctly the changes are automatic. But also keep in mind that I'm still stuck on v0.1 from Precise.

Comment: Yes, they are in fact automatic changes. You can undo accidental changes via the Undo button.

Comment: No it's not automatic, changed files are marked with green text in the list, but how do I save it. I have checked on nautilus and rhythmbox that the tag has not been changed.

Answer (score 3):

You could try easytag (my personal favorite) `sudo apt-get install easytag`

Or there is always Ex Falso `sudo apt-get install exfalso`

Comment: Can I ask one more question? Easytag able to write tag to mp3 files, I can confirm it via nautilus and rhythmbox, but in Windows and my nokia phone, there is no tag for that files. How do I write mp3 tag which can be read on all devices?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why. they both should use ID3 tags

Comment: Maybe easytag only write to certain version of ID3 tag, not all version. AFAIK there is two version of ID3 tag, winamp can write to both or just one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `kid3`. If you don't have nor want KDE libs, install `kid3-qt`