# Move part of file name to metadata

Tags: command-line, metadata, youtube-dl

I have thousands upon thousands of songs that are named as;

```
Artist - Song.mp3
Artist - Song.mp3
etc
```

What I need to do is to move everything before the "-" and add it to the metadata of the file as the "Artist"

I've tried a couple bulk renaming programs, and a few commands, but none seem to work, they just move things around in the file name. All of the commands that I've tried are "one-liners", so maybe if in terminal I could cut the part of the file name before the "-" put it in a text file and then some how use that? I'm not sure, still very new to elementary.

If you can't do this in Ubuntu, I have a Windows 7 system I can use.

Comment: Do you want to rename the mp3s as well as adding the metatag?

Comment: @andrew.46 yeah, so I'd like to turn "Acris & Infra - Justice.mp3" into "Justice.mp3" with the metadata of "Acris & Infra". If that's not possible, it's ok, I saw aconmand while I was looking for this one that can rename files before a certain character, so I can just use that. The most important thing is adding the artist info from before the " - " in the file name.

Comment: Which utility? Was it `rename`? I was experimenting with the following at the end of the `for` loop I give below: `mv "$f" "$(printf "$f" | cut -d'-' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"` but there there seemed too much danger of file loss...

Comment: FYI, the metadata for MP3 files is stored in so-called "ID3 tags"; that phrase may help you search for software to work with the metadata

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/297216/id3-tag-editor-in-13-04

Comment: OK my final effort seems fairly solid, give it a go and let me know how it runs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your songs are all labelled *exactly* in the format you have suggested: `Acris & Infra - Justice.mp3` a simple `for` loop can accomplish both tagging and renaming sequentially with one command.

Test the following on a small, backed up selection of your files:

```
for f in *.mp3; do
   artist="$(printf "$f" | cut -d '-' -f 1 | sed 's/ *$//')"
   eyeD3 --artist "$artist" "$f" 
   mv -nv "$f" "$(printf "$f" | cut -d'-' -f 2 | sed 's/^ *//')"
done
```

Two points:

1. The `mv` command has the safeguard of the `-n` or `--no-clobber` option in case any of your collection have 2 different artists / files with the same song title...
2. You will need to install `eyeD3` to do the tagging or simply change the syntax to use whichever tagger you are most happy with

Comment: OK, thank you, very very much! You've saved me countless hours...literally.  Thank you Very much, this works perfectly.

Comment: Great news :). I tinkered with it for a while until I was happy.... If you are happy with the answer consider 'Accepting' it by clicking on the little greyed out tick mark thingy near my question.

Comment: The only issue I have, is that it also renames .webm and .part files, which are almost always in the folder with the .mp3s, is there anyway I can exclude these two file extensions, those are the only 3 files that will ever be in there.

Comment: Now that is odd as the opening line: `for f in *.mp3` should find only mp3 files. Not sure about that......

Comment: I found a slightly abstract alternative, I wrote a script (super super basic) that deletes them then runs your script (thank you), the program that puts them there in the first place just replaces them when its run again :)

Comment: I added in a 'verbose' setting to the `mv` line, this should help diagnose what is happening in there....